how do I use the local CLI expo package
After running expo-cli start --tunnel  
[NOTE : UPDRADED EXPO, RAN Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned,UNINSTALLED n REINSTALLED LATEST VERSION OF EXPO ]
Still getting this error :
WARNING: The legacy expo-cli does not support Node +17. Migrate to the new local Expo CLI: https://blog.expo.dev/the-new-expo-cli-f4250d8e3421.
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                           │
│   The global expo-cli package has been deprecated.                        │
│                                                                           │
│   The new Expo CLI is now bundled in your project in the expo package.    │
│   Learn more: https://blog.expo.dev/the-new-expo-cli-f4250d8e3421.        │
│                                                                           │
│   To use the local CLI instead (recommended in SDK 46 and higher), run:   │
│   › npx expo 
Develop an app using expo start

This error output would be more legible in a pre-formatted block, delimited by triple back-ticks. Is there any reason why you wouldn't upgrade Expo client version, like the error message suggests?
